# Convert VMX to ISO

Tags: iso-image, vmware-workstation

I am trying to setup an airgapped system and got everything setup on a VMWare VM and now I need to convert it to an ISO or something similar that I can than write it to the disk.

Comment: Use VMware V to P converter..  That should work.

Comment: The process is way to complicate without understanding, which step, you are stuck on.  So [here](https://www.vmware.com/support/v2p/) is VMWare's documentation on this subject.  I personally don't know what the "Vmware V to P converter" John is refering to be honest.  Converter only supports physical to virtual in my experience.

Comment: It looks like V to P is gone.  Here is a VMware Guide.   https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1002498